# When is TempData constructed in WebViewPage<TModel>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In a class derived from `WebViewPage<TModel>` (say MyCustomWebViewPage) that is used as a base class of all views in an MVC application, I am creating and initializing another class that needs `ViewData` and `TempData`. My first attempt was to construct this class in constructor of MyCustomWebViewPage. While `ViewData` is constructed by that time, `TempData` is not (it is null). I looked for some other method I could override, may be `ConfigurePage` or `InitializePage` but none of them are virtual. So, for now, I implemented delayed construction of this class. Curious to know when TempData is constructed and if there is another method that can be overridden.